# jQuery UI draggable "jumps" on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I'm working on a website that allows users to share their art, whether it's a photo or a illustration. The thing is - the popup is too small to see the art in it's whole glory. So I decided to do that when you click on the image, it'll became full size, and to see it you can drag it to the sides. For some reason, when you drag the photo, it jumps.

Here is the website (click on the photo and then try to drag it): http://www.isrart.co.il/SO 
(please wait until the image loads)

**EDIT:** I've noticed that when I put image with the height bigger then it's width, it works perfectly, but the code is almost the same for both of them (except the asix of the scroll and the width / height);

**EDIT 2:** Now I've noticed it works perfectly on IE and FF. That's weird. So how do I fix it to work with Chrome?

Here is the JS:

```
$.fn.click2resize = function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        var f = $(this),
            i = f.children("img");

        if (i.height() == i.width()) return false;
        if (i.height() > i.width()) {
            if (i.hasClass("big")) 
                i.animate({ height: f.height(), width: getNew("width", i, f.height()), top: "50%", left: "50%", "margin-top": 0 - f.height() * 0.5, "margin-left": 0 - getNew("width", i, f.height()) * 0.5 })
                 .removeClass("big")
                 .draggable("destroy")
                 .attr("data-move", "");
            else 
                i.addClass("big").animate({ height: getNew("height", i, f.width()), width: f.width(), "margin-top": 0, "margin-left": 0, top: 0 - getNew("height", i, f.width()) / 2 + f.height() / 2, left: 0 })
                 .draggable({ 
                    axis: "y", 
                    drag: function (e, ui) { 
                        if (ui.position.top > 0) ui.position.top = 0; 
                        if (ui.position.top < 0 - i.height() + f.height()) ui.position.top = 0 - i.height() + f.height(); 
                    } 
                 })
                 .attr("data-move", "top");
        } else {
            if (i.hasClass("big"))
                i.animate({height: getNew("height", i, f.width()), width: f.width(), top: "50%", left: "50%", "margin-top": 0 - getNew("height", i, f.width()) * 0.5, "margin-left": 0 - f.width() * 0.5})
                 .removeClass("big")
                 .draggable("destroy")
                 .attr("data-move", "");
            else
                i.addClass("big")
                 .animate({height: f.height(), width: getNew("width", i, f.height()), "margin-top": 0, "margin-left": 0, top: 0, left: 0 -  getNew("width", i, f.height()) / 2 + f.height() / 2})
                 .draggable({ 
                    axis: "x", 
                    drag: function (e, ui) { 
                        if (ui.position.left > 0) ui.position.left = 0; 
                        if (ui.position.left < 0 - i.width() + f.width()) ui.position.left = 0 - i.width() + f.width();  
                    }
                 })
                 .attr("data-move", "side");
        }
    });
}
```

Sorry for my bad English, thank!

Comment: Just replace `drag` event by `stop` event in `draggable` options.

Comment: @pqdong even if I delete `drag`, it still jumps.